# How can I disable the automatic bullet function in Vue2Editor Component

Tags: vue.js, quill

I'm using the Vue2Editor and configured the toolbar as follows:

`<VueEditor v-model="position.description" :editor-toolbar="customToolbar" />`
`customToolbar: [ ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'] ],`

The trouble is, that the editor still transforms this signs "- " into

-tags. But I don't want this. How can I disable it?